# Why do I receive invalid token when I am trying to filter my data for the index?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter my data-set for the index and I receive " invalid Token " Can someone here explain to me why?

My output is:

The ouput of my data frame is:

```
Date     LastPrice MaxPric MinPrice Volume
2010-01-04  2.113   2.132   2.093   1485340.0
2010-01-05  2.171   2.2 2.113   2624534.0
2010-01-06  2.084   2.132   2.064   3233258.0
```

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_sql("XXXXXXX;", engine, index_col=['Date'])  
df.loc[2010-10-06]
```

Comment: without knowing how your data is formatted, have you tried `'2010-10-06'` instead of `2010-10-06`?

Comment: yeah but i got 'the label [2010-10-06] is not in the [index]'

Comment: which version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`df.loc` requires you to provide a label, which I see you trying to do. However, the label needs to be valid; that is present in your data frame.

After computing the mathematical expression `2010-10-06`, `df.loc[2010-10-06]` resolves to `df.loc[1994]`, which is an invalid label

`df.loc['2010-10-06']` is also invalid because it is not present in your data frame.

From your data frame, `df.loc['2010-01-04']`, `df.loc['2010-01-05']` or `df.loc['2010-01-06']` will be valid.

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score -1):

Because the correct syntax is:

```
df.loc['2010-01-06']
```

That should work :)

Comment: when i try put '    '   i recive ; 'the label [2010-10-06] is not in the [index]'

Comment: In that case, you have a different error from the one in your original post, but yo do understand that the first question is answered, correct?

Comment: I know it's there, I loaded it and used it, that's why I say it works on my end

Comment: I know it's the form bud i don´t have idea that no working

Comment: is a time series with 20 years, obviously the date is in the index, I do not know why I get that error if I use the right syntax, for something I ask here

Comment: it is not obvious that the date is in the index, since you don't provide the full dataframe. From your example, you do have '2010-01-06' but you're asking for '2010-10-06'. So maybe, and I'm guessing here, you have a typo

Comment: You're right, I apologize for the typo, but because I have the error 'the label [2010-01-04] is not in the [index]' do you have any idea if I use the appropriate syntax?

Comment: I genuinely don't understand your question. You have the proper syntax from my answer. If you ask for an index that doesn't exists then you should get an error. I tried with `df.loc['2010-01-04']` and it worked fine

Comment: To the downvoter, I would appreciate feedback, thanks!